# TMS Cloud Pack for FireMonkey

Tags: delphi

I'm testing "TMS Cloud Pack for FireMonkey", "TTMSFMXCloudDataSet".

In Google DevConsole\APIs&auth\Credentials, I created "Create credentials to access your enabled APIs." (OAuth 2.0 client IDs)

and set APPIDS.INC:

```
GDataStoreAppkey = 299488143595-ktal1uo0nsqh6s....apps.googleusercontent.com; (Client ID)

GDataStoreAppSecret = Z8eKNHi1Op...; (Client secret)
GDataStoreProject = datastore-1042;
GDataStoreDatabase = maps;
GDataStoreTable = Lists;
```

I get Errors:

> [dcc32 Error] APPIDS.INC(2): E2003 Undeclared identifier:
>   'ktal1uo0nsqh6sk3jgv32g'";
>
> [dcc32 Error] APPIDS.INC(2): E2026 Constant expression expected;
>
> [dcc32 Error] APPIDS.INC(2): E2029 ';' expected but identifier 'com' found;
>
> [dcc32 Error] APPIDS.INC(3): E2003
>
> Undeclared identifier: 'GDataStoreAppSecret'

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: -1 How could anyone here answer if you don't say what exact problem you are having?  All you've said is "I sat in my car and  ..."

Comment: Ops, sorry. I get Errors:"[dcc32 Error] APPIDS.INC(2): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ktal1uo0nsqh6sk3jgv32g'"; [dcc32 Error] APPIDS.INC(2): E2026 Constant expression expected; [dcc32 Error] APPIDS.INC(2): E2029 ';' expected but identifier 'com' found; [dcc32 Error] APPIDS.INC(3): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'GDataStoreAppSecret' .....

Comment: ... and [edit] your comment answer into your question, please. Comments disappear.

Comment: TMS has support forums available for you. Have you posted there to ask them? They're much more familiar with their code and how to use it than we would be, and this should be your **last** resort for help after exhausting all others (which includes the free support provided by the component vendor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put quotes around the `GDataStoreAppkey` constant declaration (and every other declaration in there).

Change the first line in your code block to

```
GDataStoreAppkey = '{key goes here}';
```

Apply the same logic to the other string constants.

Comment: Those aren't even assignments. They should have `:=`. And if it was, it would apply to every line.

Comment: D'Oh. Shouldn't have said assignments. Constant declarations.

Comment: I set:  GDataStoreAppkey = '{299488143595-0ta4nspksgq6vig66rgjumqab4.apps.googleusercontent.com}';
  GDataStoreAppSecret = 'yRstQbZCMYhTZGPvfftV';
  GDataStoreProject = 'datastore-1042';
  GDataStoreDatabase = 'maps';
  GDataStoreTable = 'Lists';  Program is started. But it didn't connected to server. I get an error: [Important notice] For the Windows platform, THE TRIAL VERSION OF THE Tms Cloude pack... does not support authentification throught the built-in webbrowser. The TMS Cloud Pack uses the Cromium Embeded Framework and the license prevents binary/trial distribution. Any ideas?

Comment: If the code compiles and the program starts then this question is apparently answered. You should ask a new question if you encounter further problems. That said, read the error carefully, you are trying to use a trial version in a way that is not supported.